# Regex for Phone number validation in Objective C without + symbol

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

What is the regular expression for only 13 digit phone number without the + symbol?

Number can be start from 0 to 9. Only numbers will be allowed. [No + symbol and . ]

Comment: Thanx for the answer. I am trying with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:-

```
 @"^\d{13}$"
```

or

```
 @"\d{13}"
```

`\d` means match any digit

and

`{13}` means 13 times

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am trying with this.